# How to detect corner or edge which started resizing from AIR NativeWindowBoundsEvent?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, resize, nativewindow

If you do a manual start of resizing with startResize(EdgeOrCornerString) you have to set EdgeOrCornerString. But how to detect which one Edge Or Corner has been clicked from inside (NativeWindowBoundsEvent) resizing handler? event.type gives only 'resizing', there is no edge or corner specified. 
Is it possible and if yes, how?

EDIT: I want to do custom resizing of NativeWindow, and need to know from which corner or edge user has started resizing operation.

Answer (score 1):

Just check your mouse position and compare it to you NativeWindow width and height

Comment: Yes, something like that :) I know there are 8 different possible positions, but how to calculate it precisely? some code please?

Comment: @Nemi Just use the x and y of the mouse like this answer suggests and then match the coordinates against the zones that you know would only contain one of the 8 locations you're trying to determine.

Comment: @MartyWallace How to catch screen x and y? It looks like it can't be done without native extension. For example, if I use stage's mouse coordinates, user can 'catch' edge/corner from outside nativeWindow, coordinates will stay same, and resizing would be started from wrong edge/corner. Is there method to get screen coordinates without native extension?

Comment: Compare stage.mouseX / stage.mouseY with stage.stageWidth / stage.stageHeight

Comment: @Eric, thanks, but it will only work if user starts resize by moving mouse from inside window. stage.mouseX / stage.mouseY does not update when mouse is outside window...

Comment: @Eric So, for example, user can move mouse out of window over bottom right corner, and move it around window, and start resizing from top left corner, and program would think resizing is started from bottom right corner. And then it is wrong corner detected!

Comment: I don't see how that is possible since you would catch the event when the mouse is down on a corner or edge. You say you want to calculate the stating edge or corner, i don't see the problem.

Comment: @Eric OK, how to catch those events? I can not add mouse event listener to nativeWindow, so how to do it?

Comment: just listen to the stage stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN ... , then use something like if(stage.mouseX > stage.stageWidth - 5) { to check if the mouse is down near the border, like 5 px

Comment: @Eric As you may know, stage MOUSE_DOWN event does not get dispatched when I click on edge or corner of nativeWindow (because it is not part of stage).

Comment: Try stage.nativeWindow or even NativeWindowResize which gives you want edge/corner the resizing occurs on